# Show External Activity in My Activity Android

Tags: android

I have a File Browser Application in which i have two options. Open and Email.

When clicked on Open, it open the File using External Application if available.

When clicked on Email, it start Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE Activity to send Email.

What i want is when a user clicks on Email, first View the File and Show a Button for Send on External Activity.

Is it possible to add external activity to my own activity which will have a Send Button.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can implement "[Share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646104/how-to-implement-the-share-function-of-a-android-app)" functionality in your application. This is not exactly what you want but you cannot add to external applications button from your application (it's a real security violation). So you can implement "Share" functionality and if an external application have this button (share) your application will be added to the list.