# Sharing content of your app by line, whatsapp, facebook,

Tags: android

I would like to be able to share some contents of my app by whatsapp, line (searching here i could to do it). But my question is: Is it possible to check in destination device if the application is installed, if yes, open it, if not redirect to Google Play to install the app to see the content?

Thanks. Regards.

Comment: When you trigger the sharing intent it pops up a dialog showing you what can be shared with. If those applications are installed they will show. Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646104/how-to-implement-the-share-function-of-a-android-app?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look!!

Answer (score 0):

Verify There is an App to Receive the Intent:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
```

If isIntentSafe is true, then at least one app will respond to the intent. If it is false, then there aren't any apps to handle the intent.

```
// Start an activity if it's safe
if (isIntentSafe) {
    startActivity(intent);
```

You need to raise a [specially formed intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent), to direct user to download page like this:

```
Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName);
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, marketUri);
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

Where `packageName` would be package name of your target app.

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look!!