# Have Google pop-up window account sign in want bottom nav slide-up menu like the Share menu version in pics attached for my android studio app

Tags: java, android, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

my app currently has a share button which upon click opens a bottom navigation that slides up from the bottom of the android os screen like this by [Jim Blackler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82515/jim-blackler):
[Share bottom slide-in menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQKIp.png)

my current google sign-in pop window to choose an account:
[my current google sign-in pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Gfa.png)

what I want:
[just like the share bottom slide-in google sign-in/account chooser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODW76.png)

The code I use to do the share, below, I have not successfully changed into a google sign-in prompt to match the share bottom nav slide-in prompt.

this is the Share code I use from this website [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646104/how-to-implement-the-share-function-of-a-android-app) answer by [Jim Blackler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82515/jim-blackler):

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, pageUrl);

        try {
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select an action"));
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
          // (handle error)
        }
```

my current google sign-in code:

variable:

```
private GoogleSignInClient client;
```

in "onCreate()" method:

```
GoogleSignInOptions options = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                        .build();

        client = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,options);
```

in onNavigationItemSelected method:

```
Intent intent = client.getSignInIntent();
            startActivityForResult(intent,123);
```

Your help and time will be greatly appreciated.